# C interface to R: double array to SEXP matrix

Tags: c, arrays, r

I'm learning the C interface to R using the Writing R Extensions manual, and I'm confused about conversion of native C arrays back to SEXPs. A double-precision BLAS routine, for example, produces a double array that I'm wanting to return to R. Is there a built-in function for converting an entire array to a vector or matrix SEXP type? I know I can use the `REAL()` function to obtain the array from the SEXP, but is there a "backwards" functionality, too?

As an example, the call `yada(C, ...)` requires `double *C` and provides the result in `*C`. Currently, I'm using a loop such as

```
SEXP result = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, n_result));
double *pResult = REAL(result);
for (int i = 0; i < n_result; i++) {
        pResult[i] = C[i];
}
```

to convert the values to the correct SEXP type to return, but is there a better method?

Thank you for your help. I'm new to C, and I apologize if there is a much simpler method I'm overlooking.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use RCpp? That will do all the heavy lifting of type conversions for you

Comment: Does `yada` modify its input? Then you could use `yada(REAL(result), ..)`. Or else, I guess, your alternative is `memcpy(REAL(result), C, n_result * sizeof(double))`.

Comment: @alexis_laz, yes, `yada()` does modify the input. @dww, thank you for mentioning RCpp. I went and read more about it last night. I think it can be very helpful.

Comment: @Alex: If you have control over the input to the function, you could allocate a `REALSXP` and pass `REAL(result)` instead of your `*C` to avoid allocating a `double *` of same length twice and copying it